# Force install with apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation, 10.04

I tried installing beanstalkd with `sudo apt-get install beanstalkd` (also with `-f` option) and I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  beanstalkd: Depends: libevent-1.4-2 (>= 1.4.13-stable) but it is not going to be installed
  mysql-server-5.1: Depends: mysql-client-5.1 (>= 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libmysqlclient16 (>= 5.1.21-1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.1 (>= 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: The answer to this question finally helped me 

http://askubuntu.com/a/142808/7537

Answer (score 43):

First download the deb package from repository:

```
apt-get download <package_name>
```

Install the deb file (it should be in the current folder):

```
sudo dpkg -i <downloaded_package_deb_file>
```

Comment: thanks so much for this answer. At least by doing this I can now see the the version conflicts that are causing the new package to get ignored (libstdc++6 dep in new package is newer)

Comment: `aptitude download <package_name>` also works

Comment: @Ads20000, it may have been downvoted because just `-i` won't resolve any dependency problems. However, if ineicu had shown the `--force-depends` trick, maybe the downvote would not have happened: `sudo dpkg --force-depends -i <name.deb>` will install a package even if a dependency is considered missing.

Comment: `apt-get download` completes but does not create any files in the current directory for me

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

with no package in terminal.

If this still gives the error of the dependencies then you will have to issue

```
sudo apt-get remove beanstalkd
```

then try

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server beanstalkd
```

That should install the mysql dependencies and beanstalk.

Answer (score 4):

try running `sudo apt-get --fix-missing install`

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

with no packages. And the try to install the packages again.