# how to repair ubuntu package catalog?

Tags: software-center, totem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 totem-plugins : Depends: libgnomeui-0 (>= 2.17.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libtrackerclient0 (>= 0.6.6) but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-gdata but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: totem-gstreamer (= 2.22.1-0ubuntu3.8.04.6) but it is not installable or
                          totem-xine (= 2.22.1-0ubuntu3.8.04.6) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: do you have **synaptic** installed in your system?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command which apt is suggesting i.e. 'apt-get -f install'. Try enabling multiverse and universe repositories from /etc/apt/sources.list(Its a good idea to backup the file first). Then run "sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" , "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get upgrade".

You might also want to check the following links;

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

[Force install apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140247/force-install-apt-get)