# Cannot install NVIDIA drivers due to unmet dependencies

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install CUDA and NVIDIA drivers to use a GeForce 1080 and a Titan XP GPU on my workstation.

However, running:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440
```

I got the following error, which I don't know how to solve:

```
 Reading package lists...  Done 
 Building dependency tree        
 Reading state information... Done  
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 
 requested an impossible
 situation or if you are using the unstable  distribution that some
 required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
 Incoming.  The following information may help to resolve the
 situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:  

 nvidia-driver-440 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-440 (=
 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but
 440.64.00-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libnvidia-compute-440 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 440.64.00-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libnvidia-decode-440 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libnvidia-encode-440 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-440 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2 is to be installed
                      Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: nvidia-prime (= 0.8) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libnvidia-compute-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not installable
                      Recommends: libnvidia-decode-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not installable
                      Recommends: libnvidia-encode-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not installable
                      Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not installable
                      Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not installable
                      Recommends: libnvidia-gl-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not installable 

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Info on my OS (output of `lsb_release -a`):

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Any help? :)

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140247/force-install-apt-get) help you ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried `sudo apt-get --fix-missing install` which allowed me to install the drivers. However something must be off: after reboot, I still cannot run "nvidia-smi", with the following error message: **NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running**.

Comment: What do you get when you run ```lsmod | grep nvidia ``` ?

Comment: I obtain nothing

Comment: So the driver is not loaded yet. Which version of ubuntu do you use ? Ubuntu will automatically blacklist the nouveau driver after you've installed the Nvidia's . So it should be automatically loaded after restart.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, I'm adding it to the question

Comment: I've tried to but didn't help. When I run `sudo aptitude install nvidia-driver-430` the report says **nvidia-driver-430 is already installed at the requested version (440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)**. However, I still cannot see the GPUs; e.g. I cannot use `nvidia-smi` (even after rebooting).